# how do I check if a video file was sent to a server with discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

how do I check whether a video file was sent to a discord server?

I tried using

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):  # Event handler for income messages
    if message.author == client.user:
        return None

    response = 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/690944063888687114/724771151041265704/thats_my_meme_now.mp4'

    if video in message.content:
        await message.channel.send(
            response)
```

but that gives me the following error:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\seanb\Desktop\python projects\discord bot\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/seanb/Desktop/python projects/discord bot/discord bot.py", line 21, in on_message
    if video in message.content:
NameError: name 'video' is not defined
```

Comment: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=message#discord.Message.content `message.content` is a string. You have to look under `message.attachments` see the docs.

Answer (score 0):

This code loops through all video formats and checks if any of the attached files is in any of these formats.

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.bot:
        return
    for a in message.attachments:
        for e in ['3g2','3gp','amv','asf','avi','drc','f4a','f4b','f4p','f4v','flv','gif','gifv','m2ts','m2v','m4p','m4v','mkv','mng','mov','mp2','mp4','mpe','mpeg','mpg','mpv','mts','mxf','nsv','ogg','ogv','qt','rm','rmvb','roq','svi','ts','vob','webm','wmv','yuv']:
            if a.filename[-len(e)-1:]==f'.{e}':
                await message.channel.send('https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/690944063888687114/724771151041265704/thats_my_meme_now.mp4')
                return
```

Comment: i tried it But i get this error: Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\seanb\Desktop\python projects\discord bot\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/seanb/Desktop/python projects/discord bot/discord bot.py", line 16, in on_message
    if a.name[-len(e)-1:]==f'.{e}':
AttributeError: 'Attachment' object has no attribute 'name'

Comment: @MuhamadLee hello two years later! it says `filename`, not `name`.